# Property '$axios' does not exist on type 'Store<RootState>'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to use Axios within my store ts file like in the picture, the code is working, however, I get this error from VS Code. In my tsconfig.json, I have included the "@nuxtjs/axios" in types as well. Tried to restart the VS Code and the server but didn't help.

Can please someone help?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed the issue by removing type `ActionTree<RootState, RootState>`

I am not sure whether this is right but code is working and error went away